# Ubuntu/Win10 Dual Boot - Can't boot into Windows from GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I'm running a (K)Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10 Dual Boot. I can boot into Windows if I choose the corresponding entry in the UEFI Boot Menu, however I can't boot Windows from GRUB. It is correctly autodetected, but selecting that entry gives me

```
error, no such device: 6C1B-07CC.
error: file '/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi'
```

Ubuntu is installed on */dev/sdb*, Windows on */dev/sda*.
I've double checked and the UUID is correct:

```
> lsblk --output NAME,UUID,SIZE
NAME                     UUID                                     SIZE
sda                                                             931,5G
├─sda1                   0FE3-52CE                                450M
├─sda2                   6C1B-07CC                                100M
├─sda3                                                             16M
├─sda4                   1E1E1FE31E1FB12F                       118,7G
└─sda5                   0ef33cbe-3e42-4213-a21b-e6c2b1ef2a6c   812,3G
```

The file mentioned above exists as well (I guess otherwise Windows wouldn't be able to boot at all).

Here's the relevant section of */boot/grub/grub.cfg*:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-6C1B-07CC' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  6C1B-07CC
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6C1B-07CC
    fi
    chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

Any idea why GRUB can't find that device / partition?

Thanks!

Comment: First thing to try is running `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't mention that: The `grub.cfg` was generated by running `update-grub`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)